# atoi and strtol produce erroneous results

Tags: arrays, c, pointers, atoi, strtol

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    char *filename = "Sayilar.txt";
    FILE *fp = fopen("D:\\WWW\\Yazilim\\cLionProject\\untitled3\\Sayilar.txt", "r");

    if (fp == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error: could not open file %s", filename);
        return 1;
    }

    // reading line by line, max 256 bytes
    const unsigned MAX_LENGTH = 256;
    char buffer[MAX_LENGTH];

    while (fgets(buffer, MAX_LENGTH, fp))
        printf("%s\n", buffer);

    // close the file
    fclose(fp);

    char *token;
    char *dizi[] = {"1","2"};
    long int dizi2[] = {1, 2};
    int num1, num2;

    token = strtok(buffer, "#");
    printf("token = %s\n", token);
    //num1 = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
    num1 = atoi(token);
    dizi[0] = token;
    dizi2[0] = strtol(dizi[0], NULL, 10);


    token = strtok(NULL, "#");
    printf("token = %s\n", token);
    //num2 = strtol(token, NULL, 10);
    num2 = atoi(token);
    dizi[1] = token;
    dizi2[1] = strtol(dizi[1], NULL, 10);

    printf("%s, %s\n",dizi[0], dizi[1]);
    printf("%ld, %ld\n",dizi2[0], dizi2[1]);
    printf("%d, %d",num1, num2);


    return 0;
}
```

How would I go about converting a two-digit number (type char*) to an int?

I want to convert the value from token to integer value
atoi and strtol produce erroneous results

output is

```
815102162524#622101830754

token = 815102162524

token = 622101830754

815102162524, 622101830754

2147483647, 2147483647

-941623716, -668427166
```

Comment: These numbers are too big for being `int`.

Comment: `atoi()` has no error checking builtin; `strtol()` does. Use `strtol()` and check for errors! `errno = 0; foo = strtol(text, &error_checking_pointer, 10); /* check errno, check error_checking_pointer */`

Comment: ı tried long int, same problem

Comment: Pretty sure the problem is not the same. `atoi` is converting to `int`, use `strtol`.

Comment: [fits with factors of room to spare](https://godbolt.org/z/Peha33Y64). Note that I'm not error checking `strtol` here, you can find out more info about how to do that on its [man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strtol.3.html) and by googling around. You're saying "same problem", I suspect you're not using the correct `printf` format specifier to print a `long` (it's `"%ld"`).

Comment: Does your input file really contain numbers like 815102162524 and 622101830754?  Those are really big numbers.  Depending on your processor and compilation model, they might not even fit in `long int`.  They're 40-bit numbers.  You might need `long long int`, and `strtoll()`.

Comment: The reason you got different results for `atoi` versus `strtol` is that `strtol` is has well-defined behavior on overflow and other errors, while `atoi` does not.  Since 815102162524 doesn't fit in a `long int` on your machine, `strtol` gave you the largest number it could, as it's supposed to: 2147483647.  `atoi`, on the other hand, did something crazy.  (It essentially took 815102162524 % 4294967296, giving 3353343580, which when interpreted by `%d` as a 2's complement signed integer gave -941623716.)

Comment: Clearly neither `815102162524` nor `622101830754` are "_a two-digit number_".  They both have 12 digits.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main(void) {
    char buffer[] = "815102162524#622101830754\n";
    long long int num1, num2;
    char *p;
    printf("Long long %u bits\n",sizeof(num1)*8);

    num1 = strtoll(buffer, &p, 10);
    printf("token = %c\n", *p);
    num2 = strtoll(p+1,NULL,10);

    printf("%lld, %lld\n",num1,num2);
}
```

Output

```
Long long 64 bits
token = #
815102162524, 622101830754
```

Comment: @SteveSummit Fixed for longlong

Comment: Whoops, now it is